# Way to dynamically build up form controls with both value and label

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have just started using reactive forms. The use case is that I get my filters from an API, then I dynamically build up my form controls like this.
The constructor:

```
constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
) {
  this.typesArray = this.fb.group({});
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    typesArray:  this.typesArray,
  });
}

// a bit further I do this after finishing an API call:
response.forEach((type: any) => {
  (this.form.get('typesArray') as FormGroup).addControl(type.id, new FormControl(false));
});
```

This results in a row of checkboxes:

```
<div *ngFor="let Type of objectKeys(typesArray.controls)">
    <ion-checkbox class="ion-no-margin" type="checkbox" [formControlName]="Type"></ion-checkbox>
    <ion-label class="ion-no-margin" class="ml-2">**HERE I WANT THE LABEL**</ion-label>
</div>
```

The value is binded by [formControlName], which is the type Id. **Is there a way to also add the label (type.title for example "Book", "DVD") to the form controls?**

I would like to prevent having to build up a separate array with my values and labels just to show the correct label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need separate array.
Title or any other field can be resolved by index from original filters array.

Working sample:

```js
export interface Filter {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    selected: boolean;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-demo',
    templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./demo.component.scss'],
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

    filters: Filter[] = [{ id: 1, title: 'Book', selected: true }, { id: 2, title: 'DVD', selected: false }];
    form: FormGroup;

    get typesArray(): FormArray {
        return this.form.get('typesArray') as FormArray;
    }

    constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            typesArray: new FormArray([]),
        });

        this.filters.forEach((filter) => {
            this.typesArray.push(this.formBuilder.control(filter.selected));
        });

        this.typesArray.valueChanges.subscribe((checkboxValues: boolean[]) => {
            const selectedFilters = checkboxValues
                .map((selected, index) => {
                    return { ...this.filters[index], selected };
                })
                .filter((filters) => filters.selected);

            console.log(selectedFilters);
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let control of typesArray.controls; let i = index;">
        <td>{{ filters[i].title }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" [formControl]="control"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but am I right when I say that formArray is not the "good practice" thing to do here: "FormArray is an alternative to FormGroup for managing any number of unnamed controls".  This is more meant for things where user input is involved? I also updated my question to show how I build up my formGroup.

Comment: This quote only means that with FormGroup each child controls needs to have name, but in case of FormArray they don't.
FormArray and FormGroup are all about user input.
I'll provide few changes to my answer, to make it similar to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification John! will test this out soon and let you know.